# How to fix "scrollViewDidScroll: unrecognized selector sent to instance" ERROR in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, github, uiscrollview

[image: My Storyboard setup for the using the PageMenu]

I am using the this [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu), and it works great alone with a Tabbar controller, however if i use it with a Nav bar it throws the following error the second or third time i click on its tab,

error: error code: 
[NSCFString scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146a0bd0

ODDLy enough this error only occurs on the Device, in the simulator it works great. I can keep clicking the between tabs on simulator the error never occurs.

HERE is the [LINK to the PageMenu Class](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/blob/master/Classes/CAPSPageMenu.swift#L463)

Comment: try to add debug breakpoints for "All exceptions" and symbolic breakpoint "objc_exception_throw". It can show u line of code where error.

Comment: More than likely you are losing the "delegate" of the scrollview due to the navigation bar. The way around this is somewhat complex. There could be a quick fix for this depending on how you set up the navigation controller to handle this or how you set up the navigation bar, but if it turns out that an easy delegation handling method you set up wrong or is wrong in the library doesn't work then the only other route is to subclass a UINavgaiotnController and intercept method calls with internal delegates and forwardinvocation.

Comment: I'd toss you a solution if I had an easy solution for you, but the solution that would work for this will just be extremely confusing and it's in Objective C. It would help for you to show us how you've set this up so we could possibly iron out any delegate methods that are declared incorrectly or interpreted wrong by your own code or the library.

Comment: I added the storyboard structure picture , will this be helpful ?

Comment: I also added the link to PageMenu Class code.